# Pointcut to match all calls to public methods, except calls to self

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am attempting to write an aspect which monitors calls to public methods on a variety of objects, but ignore calls to self. For this, I have an aspect like this:

```
abstract aspect MonitorPublicMethodCalls {

  abstract pointcut matchingType();
  pointcut matchingCall(): call(public * *(..));
  pointcut notSelf();

  Object around(Object t): matchingType() && matchingCall()  && notSelf() {
    // do something useful with the call
    if(/* allow call? */) {
      return proceed();
    } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Badness!");
    }
  }
}
```

This will monitor all calls to all public methods, but in order to ignore calls to self I would really like to define `notSelf` as something like

`pointcut notSelf(Object o): target(o) && !this(o)`

However for this I get an error: "negation does not allow binding" on the negation of `this(o)`. Right now as a workaround I check within the advice body whether the target is equal to this and if so bypass the other logic, however this means the aspect is being weaved into more places than are actually necessary. Is it possible to define a constraint to avoid calls to self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pointcut selfAndTarget(Object tgt, Object thiz) : target(tgt) && this(thiz)
pointcut notSelf(): selfAndTarget(tgt, thiz) && if(tgt != thiz)
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't understood what the conditional expressions were for until seeing this concrete example. However, according to the AspectJ documentation if pointcut expressions "will be evaluated at run-time for each candidate join point":

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3729

So, this ultimately ends up being a slightly cleaner version of what I was already doing in the body of my advice as a workaround. I'm hoping someone might know a way of doing this that will allow the join point candidates to be eliminated statically.

Comment: There is no way to statically determine if the target of a call is the same as the caller. Objects are a runtime concept and thus needs decision making during runtime.

Comment: In general, yes I guess you're right. There are the obvious "this.x()" type calls but the wider case of determining whether you have an alias to yourself is much harder to infer statically. Anyway, as no-one else is offering any options I'll accept your answer, thanks for the help!